# Python Bigquery to_dataframe function is blocked when gunicorn is run with worker class gevent

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gunicorn, gevent, eventlet

When I run my flask app with worker-class=gevent on gunicorn, the server blocks.

- gunicorn command
  gunicorn app:app --workers=5 --worker-class=gevent --threads=5 --timeout=1800 --log-level=DEBUG
- Source code

```
query = '...'
query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)\
query_job.to_dataframe()# to_dataframe function where block occurs
```

- Source code where a block in the bigquery library occurs (lines 678 to 680 of the google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py file)

```
try:
    frame = worker_queue.get(timeout=_PROGRESS_INTERVAL) # this point
    yield frame
```

- Python library version

  - python=3.7.10
  - gunicorn=20.1.0
  - gevnet=21.1.2
  - eventlet=0.30.2
  - google-cloud-bigquery=2.20.0
  - google-cloud-bigquery-storage=2.4.0
  - google-cloud-core=1.6.0
  - pyarrow=4.0.0

The same happens when worker-class is an eventlet. It does not occur when worker-class is gthread or sync.
The block in _pandas_helpers.py is executed in the following syntax, is it a thread-related problem?

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=total_streams) as pool:
```

Why do blocks happen?